Drop Scheduler Jobs that created by Chains
I have scheduler jobs that automatically generated by scheduler chain, and it loops.
So I already stop the chain process, and I want to drop thousands of scheduler jobs that creates.
I can't delete it from my schema browser cause it's a lot and make my memory full.
So I try this
Begin
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB (
    JOB_NAME =>'RUN_CHAIN$UW_RPT_17193',
    force=>true
    );
END;
/

but the error is
[Error] Execution (1: 1): ORA-27475: "GIA.RUN_CHAIN$UW_RPT_17193" must be a job
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 213
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 657
ORA-06512: at line 2

I can't drop the jobs even I input the correct job name, it's like the job still there but it can't be found.
any suggestion for this problem?

Try your code with schema name concatenated to job name
Begin
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB (
    JOB_NAME => 'SHEMA_NAME.RUN_CHAIN$UW_RPT_17193',
    force=>true
    );
END;

and also be sure that the job is really exists

I've already tried "JOB_NAME => 'GIA.RUN_CHAIN$UW_RPT_17193'". But the error is same

and are the job really exists? (check data dictionary)

in this query "select * from sys.dba_scheduler_jobs" I got the owner name and job name, and it's GIA.RUN_CHAIN$UW_RPT_17193

Can you send, job creation script?
